# Maximo workflow task node actions

Tags: maximo

I'm wanting to modify an existing workflow in workflow designer to give 3 routing options for a user instead of 2. It says that a task node can only have one positive and one negative line. What's the work-around for this?

I don't think an action group would work since I want 3 different 'To node's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm away from a system to confirm, but I believe you are looking for a "Manual Input Node". I think that one will present any number of options to the user. The options will be based on the label of the lines coming out of the node and workflow will follow the path of the line the user picks.